# Xcodebuild failed exit code 65 - ios

Tags: ios, macos, xcode8, nativescript

Receiving the following error when doing a

**tns run -v ios**

(mac is running High Sierra and xcode is current, certificates are in place, etc). any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here the error:

`Building project...
Xcode build...
=== BUILD TARGET HelloWorld OF PROJECT HelloWorld WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: framework not found FileProvider for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
=== BUILD TARGET HelloWorld OF PROJECT HelloWorld WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
error: the following command failed with exit code 1 but produced no further output
Ld build/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HelloWorld normal x86_64
** BUILD FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: B71912B9-B650-4EBF-AB43-3383136CB95F. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HelloWorld/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js`

Comment: Solved. Issue required moving to the most current version of xcode, 9+

Comment: Seeing the same problem, but with a freshly upgraded xcode 10.

Comment: @DarkNeuron were you able to solve this issue after upgrding to xcode 10

Comment: Yeah, you can switch to the legacy build system under File>Workspace Settings. If that doesn't help, you might be able to find a solution here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3909

Answer (score 2):

run `tns build ios --clean --log trace` first ，if the log trace is related to some plugin, use whose latest version in the package.json file , run `npm install`, than run `tns build ios --clean --log trace` again.

if it not work, run `tns prepare ios --release` and open `{app-name}/platforms/ios/{app-name}.xcworkspace` file with xcode , try run it, xcode will tell you where is the problem.